# Can I use the ROOT path in Server.xml while using the project path?

Tags: java, tomcat

```
<Server.xml>
 <Context docBase="Project5" path="" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Project5"/>
```

I am using the above code.
As a result, the project name was deleted from the URL path as desired.
ex) http:// 172.0.0.1/Project5/Main.jsp -> http:// 172.0.0.1/Main.jsp

Instead, the TOMCAT ROOT path has been changed to the project folder (Webapps/Project5).

But I hope Webapps/ROOT is the default ROOT path.

Is there a way to maintain the ROOT path while maintaining the URL path condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can't have two web applications mapped to the same context path in the same host.